# Найти и скачать файлы на сайте при помощи urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Необходимо найти файлы определенного расширения и скачать их, но выбивает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, помогите пожалуйста

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote
import os
import re
window = Tk()
def writeFile(filename, text):
    with open(path.get() + "/" + filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as handler:
        handler.write(text)
def recursiveDownload(addr, n, isMain = False):
    if n == 0:
        return
    try:
        response = request.urlopen(addr)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

    text = soup.prettify()
    text = text.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    if isMain:
        writeFile('index.html', text)
    else:
        filename = addr.replace(address.get() + "/", '')
        writeFile(filename, text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
        link = link.get('href')
        if (link is not None) and ('/' not in link) and ('?' not in link):
            recursiveDownload(address.get() + '/' + link, n - 1)
def selectPath():
    path.set(filedialog.askdirectory())

def clone():
    if os.path.exists(path.get()) is False:
        messagebox.showwarning(None, "Введите путь для сохранения копии сайта.")
        return
    recursiveDownload(address.get(), depth.get(), True)

    templ=re.compile('files/\w+\\' +ext )
    mathes=re.findall(templ, str(g.response.body))
    for i in mathes:
        mp3file = urllib2аахах.urlopen(address+i)    
        with open(path+i.replace('files/',''),'wb') as output:
            output.write(mp3file.read())
address = StringVar(value="https://wiki.com")
depth = IntVar()
path = StringVar()
ext= StringVar()

Label(window, text="Сайт:").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(window, text="Глубина анализа: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(window, text="Путь сохранения:").grid(row=2, column=0)

Label(window, text="Расширение файла:").grid(row=3, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=ext).grid(row=3, column=1)
Entry(window, textvariable=address).grid(row=0, column=1)
Spinbox(window, textvariable=depth, from_=1, to=10, width=18).grid(row=1, column=1)
Entry(window, textvariable=path).grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(window, text="Начать", command=clone).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
Button(window, text="Выбрать", command=selectPath).grid(row=2, column=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: ext.get() забыли?

Comment: подскажите куда именно это написать, а то уже вообще потерялся

Comment: templ=re.compile('files/\w+\\' +ext )

Comment: mathes=re.findall(templ, str(g.response.body))
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
теперь такая ошибка, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы сами этот код писали?

Comment: нет, к сожалению, но очень нужно доделать это задание

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100909/discussion-between--and-yavis).